# NoMethodError: Undefined method `failure_message` - Shoulda

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, shoulda

I am trying to use `Shoulda` to test my user class as followed:

**user_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'
include Devise::TestHelpers

class UserTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  should have_many(:holidays)
  should have_many(:hopsital_bookings)
  should have_and_belong_to_many(:roles)
  should belong_to(:hospital)

end
```

User.rb

```
  belongs_to :hospital
  belongs_to :department
  has_many :holidays
  has_many :hospital_bookings
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
```

When I run `rake test` I get the following output: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J047X.png).

Any ideas what I am missing here and why this is not working because it should!

Comment: What is in your `test_helper.rb` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to:

1) Put at your gem file:

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda'
end

2) run bundle install